# Socket.io on Shared Host (Node.js app): Is it possible?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, hosting

Is it possible to host a node.js app on a shared host plan (ex. Namecheap) that uses socket.io?

I've been told that incoming ports cannot be opened, and I'm unable to run at root access on ports 80 and 443.

What is the best way to host a socket.io node.js app?

Comment: _What is the best way to host a socket.io node.js app?_ -- depends on your project goals.

Comment: I'm creating a video conference app. It almost works, but fails to create a websocket connection so it falls back to xhr and eventually dies.